# Keyframes on starry night animation

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I'm just learning css3 animation and am trying to understand [Night sky with twinkling stars - CSS3 only](https://codepen.io/WebSonick/pen/vjmgu?editors=1100)

I can understand the cloud movement but not so much on the star blinking animation.

From what I see, 
`http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/360/images/stars.png` is just a static image with stars on the dark background.

`http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/360/images/twinkling.png` is only a dark background(I don't see anything particular here unless I missed something?) I see that animation `move-twink-back` just moves this `png` to achieve this animation. How so?

```css
.twinkling{
  background:transparent url(http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/360/images/twinkling.png) repeat top center;
  z-index:1;

  -moz-animation:move-twink-back 200s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation:move-twink-back 200s linear infinite;
  -o-animation:move-twink-back 200s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation:move-twink-back 200s linear infinite;
  animation:move-twink-back 200s linear infinite;
}



@keyframes move-twink-back {
    from {background-position:0 0;}
    to {background-position:-10000px 5000px;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/360/images/twinkling.png` is not only a dark `background`. it has some dark areas with different `opacity` levels, so the effect is basically happening in a smart way when it fades in and out through `animation` using these variations of `opacity`.

Open the image in a new tab, press `F12` to open `DevTools` (in Chrome or Firefox), find `body` element, change its `background` to `white` and you'll see it better.

Comment: I see.. so it's using a 10*10 repeating itself with a dark background to simulate the blinking effect. Thanks!!